# FBSDKCorekit.h, FBSDKCopying.h file note found using Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, fbsdk

For some odd reason after adding an unrelated pod I have been receiving an error message during the build process that indicates FBSDKCorekit.h, FBSDKCopying.h and FBSDKButton.h files are not found. I have followed countless suggestions changing properties in the projects build settings based on suggestions I've found on stackoverflow; however, none seem to work.

I am using Cocoapods so I attempted to uninstall and reinstall it as well as the pre-release version. I cleared the pod cache as well as removed the actual pods folder and podfile.lock and the xcworkspace and re-installed the pod into the project; however, I still recieve the error.

I also removed the project cache and rebuilt it...

Any assistance would be appreciated

> Podfile

```
# define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.4'
# using Swift
use_frameworks!
#
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

# disable bitcode in every sub-target
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
        end
    end
end

target 'MyApp' do
#   other pods
    pod ...
#   Facebook
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit' , '4.9.0-beta2'//4.8 gives same issue
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.9.0-beta2'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '4.9.0-beta2'
#   Uber(New pod added)
    pod 'UberRides' //actually just realized it's just a wrapper for very simple calls

#   ==============================================================
#   Sets the inheritance mode for the tests target inheriting 
#   only the search paths   
    target 'MyAppTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be some bug in cocoapods 1.0.0 Beta versions.
Falling back to v0.39.0 fixes the error.
You might need to remove cocoapods latest beta you have that installed, [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/686317) should help.

Comment: Thanks a lot I had this issue for a few days

Answer (score 47):

Happened with me after update to cocoapods 1.0.0.beta.6

Next helped to me:

- Xcode -> Product -> Clean
- Xcode -> Product -> ⌥ + Clean
- close Xcode
- `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
- open Xcode and build (was no need to reinstall pods)

Comment: what is Alt + Clean? where is Alt? >.<

Comment: wow! what are you? your answer just came in like an oracle and solved unknown problems!

Comment: This did not work for me but a more thorough clean as described at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4713#issuecomment-221957685 did.

Comment: @RainCast, lol, that's an "Alt" key on your keyboard %) Called "Opt/Option" some time ago.

Comment: oh, now I see it, it is called option ... :D

Comment: Great answer! Thanks.

Comment: This was really useful and helped me gain 2.6 GB disk space back again!

Comment: How dumb I was not to try clean the build folder and removing derived data! I wasted 2 hours from trying to fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to fallback to `v0.39.0`.

I have currently the following versions:

```
1. cocoapods-0.38.2
2. cocoapods-0.39.0
3. cocoapods-1.0.0.beta.2
4. cocoapods-1.0.0.beta.3
```

For me this issue appeared only in `beta.5`.

So if you want 1.0 go for `beta.3`.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 12.5 and Cocoapods 1.10.1 here.

I had this issue when cocoapods updated `FBSDKCoreKit` to 11.0

I downgraded to 9.3 and it worked again.

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 9.3'
```